# initialise firebase in nodejs expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

i want to initialise a firebase (not firebase-admin) instance in Node.

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

const firebaseConfig = {
  //...
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

this won't work cause node works with commonjs exports and you can't require from firebase cause there is no exports..

Comment: Can you set the type to module in your package.json ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase says:

> This SDK is intended for end-user client access from environments such
> as the Web, mobile Web (e.g. React Native, Ionic), Node.js desktop
> (e.g. Electron), or IoT devices running Node.js. If you are instead
> interested in using a Node.js SDK which grants you admin access from a
> privileged environment (like a server), you should use the Firebase
> Admin Node.js SDK.

So use [`firebase-admin`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup/) instead if you are planning to use firebase with the backend.

Install with `npm install firebase-admin --save`

To initialize define a variable export `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/service-account-file.json"` and

```js
const { initializeApp } = require('firebase-admin/app');
initializeApp()
```